# Firebase database data not visible in page hosted at Google app Engine

Tags: angularjs, google-app-engine, firebase

I have used Angular to write my page and used firebase to store the form data. The posted data is getting added in the database and I'm able to see them in the localhost. But when once I hosted in Google app engine, I'm not able to see any of my posts. Everything else works perfectly fine.

URL: http://homigo-1133.appspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

you should add http://homigo-1133.appspot.com/ to the Authorized Domains for OAuth Redirects in Fiebase User Login & Authentication.

Comment: That was great but. I'm getting this:

Error: Unable to parse the domain specified (''). Please specific a domain using the format 'domain.com', or 'subdomain.domain.com'.

Comment: try with homigo-1133.appspot.com